# mongodb covert single row into multiple based on some condition in aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have fromDate field and toDate field in a row/record which represents a period, I want to break that row into multiple rows, means if the from and to date represents period of 5 days, it results in 5 rows, is that possible using aggregation pipeline with $project.

```
source:  { from: "01-01-2020", to: "05-01-2020", total: 100}
result: [
{ date: "01-01-2020", amount: 20 },
{ date: "02-01-2020", amount: 20 }
{ date: "03-01-2020", amount: 20 }
{ date: "04-01-2020", amount: 20 }
{ date: "05-01-2020", amount: 20 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :... https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qp1XjOvJxyf

its really out of the box requirements and usually application should be doing such logic, However as mongodb provides powerful features so you can achieve it using below:

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "daysbetween": {
        "$add": [
          1,
          {
            "$divide": [
              {
                "$subtract": [
                  {
                    $dateFromString: {
                      dateString: "$to"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    $dateFromString: {
                      dateString: "$from"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              86400000
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "fromDate": {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$from"
        }
      },
      "toDate": {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$to"
        }
      }
    },
    
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "daysbetween": {
        "$function": {
          "body": "function(daysbetween,total,fromDate) {try {var arr =[]; for(let i=0;i< daysbetween;i++) { var amt=total/daysbetween; var date = new Date(fromDate); date.setDate(date.getDate()+i); ; ;arr.push({'amount': amt, 'date':date})} row_number+= 1;} catch (e) {row_number= 0;}return arr;}",
          "args": [
            "$daysbetween",
            "$total",
            "$fromDate"
          ],
          "lang": "js"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$daysbetween"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      date: {
        $dateToString: {
          date: "$daysbetween.date",
          format: "%d-%m-%Y"
        }
      },
      amount: "$daysbetween.amount"
    }
  }
])
```

here we have first converted dates from string then calculated difference, then using set added array for all days between dates and then unwinded subarray of dates to get desired result. finally projected only required data. Please test it out for all possible use cases and then only use it as Here I did not do null check of date format checks.